# Jenkins cannot be accessed by ip address even from the same computer

Tags: windows, jenkins

I downloaded the jenkins war file in my private computer. I started the jenkins using java -jar jenkins.war. I can access the jenkins at localhost:8080. I have inbound and outbound rules for allowing port 8080 in my firewall. I get my ipv4 address from command prompt using 'ipconfig'. However I am unable to access the jenkins using this ip from other systems in the same network. I am even unable to access it from my own systems incognito mode with http://ipadress:8080. Cant the jenkins in my machine be accessed by others?

I also tried installing jenkins as service but could not access it. I tried changing the jenkins url in setting to http://ipadress:8080 also.

Comment: Did you configure Jenkins to use localhost or the real IP address of that machine?

Comment: @Simon I dont know what you meant by configure jenkins? I just started it with java -jar jenkins.war command, and in jenkins setting, added the ip that I found out by ipconfig